error while trying to login with google using firebase
I get:

Error signing in: [firebase_auth/invalid-credential] The supplied auth credential is incorrect, malformed or has expired. [ ID Token issued at 1733745109 is stale to sign-in.

What is the reason here?
It was working fine for one login then, as i logged out and trying to login again, it seems to not work.
class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(); // GoogleSignIn instance

  // Sign in method with Google Sign-In and Firebase Authentication
  Future<User?> signIn() async {
    try {
      // Step 1: Trigger the Google Sign-In process
      final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();

      if (googleUser == null) {
        // If the user cancels the sign-in process
        print("Google Sign-In canceled.");
        return null;
      }

      // Step 2: Retrieve authentication details from Google
      final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

      // Step 3: Create Firebase credential from Google authentication details
      final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
        idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
      );

      // Step 4: Sign in to Firebase with the Google credentials
      final UserCredential userCredential = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);
      return userCredential.user;
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error signing in with Google: $e");
      return null;
    }
  }

  // Get the current user from Firebase
  Future<User?> getCurrentUser() async {
    try {
      User? user = _firebaseAuth.currentUser;
      if (user != null) {
        await user.getIdToken(true); // Force token refresh if needed
      }
      return user;
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error getting current user: $e");
      return null;
    }
  }

  // Check if the user is signed in with Firebase
  bool isSignedIn() {
    return _firebaseAuth.currentUser != null;
  }

  // Manually refresh the token before performing authenticated operations
  Future<String?> getFreshToken() async {
    try {
      User? user = _firebaseAuth.currentUser;
      if (user != null) {
        String? token = await user.getIdToken(true); // Forces refresh
        return token;
      } else {
        print('No user is signed in');
        return null;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error refreshing token: $e');
      return null;
    }
  }
}


Did you clean google signin session when you log out?

You've forced a refresh of the firebase idToken by setting true in the getIdToken function. However, You are still having issues with incorrect credentials. It seems to be related to my Google login session. This means that your Google login session may have expired. To resolve the issue, you can clear your Google sign-in session when you log out. I will provide sample code.
final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(); // GoogleSignIn instance

Future<void> logOut() async {
    await _firebaseAuth.signOut();
    await _googleSignIn.signOut();
}

So when you logout, you will run the logOut function and it will clear firebase and google credentials and it will solve your issue.

I actually had ```final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(); // GoogleSignIn instance
Future logOut() async {
await _firebaseAuth.signOut();
await _googleSignIn.signOut();
}``` I didn't include it here as it said "your description looks too much code" when i was trying to post the question. I actually have it in my code, still error.

its working again, idk how. now i tried it after 30 mins and its working. should i delete the question or what.

Oh, I see. sounds good it working again. I think if you keep your question, other people might see it and get ideas.
